# Why does this function return undefined

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am e newbie with javascript and having trouble figuring out why this function returns  undefined. After some research I thought it was hoisting and declared all variables global but thar didnt solve the problem.

```
var inC = 2;
var inMat = "EO";
var prijs = 100;
var inA = 50;
var inB = 25;

function rand(soort) {
   return soort * ((inA.value/100) + ((inB.value * 2 ) / 100))
   };

function randberekening() {
   if (inC.value == 2 && inMat.value == "EQ"){
      return rand(prijs)
      };
   };

alert(randberekening());
```

Fiddle available -  https://jsfiddle.net/hudehar/g2rvxd74/

Comment: you don't have any return statements in your functions...

Comment: You aren't returning anything.  So of course the return value is undefined.

Comment: All functions return `undefined` .... unless you specifically return something else.

Comment: I have adjusted the code, but it still returns undefined. Is there something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

If you return something from function then it will return the value, if you didn't return anything then it will return undefined.

```
function test(){
  return true
}
console.log(test())// return true;

function returnNothing(){
 console.log("hello there")
}
console.log(returnNothing()) // return undefined.
```